# How to execute GetItemLinqQueryable returning int asynchronously?

Tags: .net, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to execute asynchronously such query, which returns an int?

Example and my use case:

```
var place = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<GuildModel>()
            .Where(m => m.Score < guild.Resource.Score)
            .Count()
```

If I understand this correctly, I should use ToFeedIterator, like I did with queries returning documents, but here Count() returns only int. I can use allowSynchronousQueryExecution but it seems fishy. :)

Comment: `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq` contains an `CountAsync()` which you can use in combination with `GetItemLinqQueryable<T>()`.

Comment: Oh my, didn't notice that, that you so much!

Comment: @NotFound post your solution as an answer so that it will help other community members the same type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq` contains an `CountAsync()` which you can use in combination with `GetItemLinqQueryable<T>()`.